# MySQL Set Session wait_timeout, interactive_timeout not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm improving a web app done in Codeigniter to control how many people can save a row concurrently.

Since Codeigniter doesn't include the usual 'For Update' or 'Lock In Share Mode' functionalities, I've done a number of custom queries and have For Update.

The issue is that the rows are locked, but only for a short period of time (10 seconds) even though I've set the session to a longer wait timeout, I've even set global wait timeouts and the transaction still is killed within 10-15 seconds.

If I implement a sleep function to test, the rows lock properly for however long I set the transaction to sleep for.

If I use MySQL Workbench, the wait timeout works as intended.

```
    $this->db->query('SET SESSION autocommit = 0');
    $this->db->query('SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE');
    $this->db->query('SET SESSION innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1');
    $this->db->query('SET SESSION interactive_timeout = 28000');
    $this->db->query('SET SESSION wait_timeout = 28000');
    $this->db->trans_start();

    $query = //Query is here

    $data = $this->db->query("{$sql} FOR UPDATE;")->row();

    return $data;
```

Comment: `interactive_timeout` doesn't apply to programed connections. Are you wanting to control the rate of changes or the absolute number of changes? Is this a business requirement or are you trying to just preserve performance. Which MySQL version? Some newer versions have a newer set of available features that might be usable.

Comment: The update statement might be useful too.

Comment: Originally I was on MySQL 5.6.45, but now I'm on MariaDB 10.2.31 stable. I'm trying to keep a lock alive in a module in order to prevent two people/processes from updating the same record. 

The update statement(s) is very large, probably too large to display here.

Comment: MySQL/MariaDB already prevent concurrent updates to the same record. When that two people/process are an update to them record, one, or maybe both depending on query, will get a deadlock exception and you'll need to handle that exception in your application. You also don't seen a `select for .. update` unless you're trying to preserve harder to obtain rows locked before some easier SQL statements in the same transaction.

Comment: Our software still has problems with lost updates. Where one user will overwrite another user, or where users overwrite themselves if they open additional windows.

where it says '//Query is here' (query is very long) I have a select and used 'for update' with the record. It works within the short 7-10 second window, but the persistent connection is killed too quickly to be effective.

Comment: Some explicit business row locking maybe: `update table set locked_until=DATE_ADD(NOW() + 20 MINUTES, user=%s WHERE (locked_until < NOW() OR user=%s) AND column=%i` - and examine rows affected.